# Reload div with filtered data from SQL when checkbox is checked/clicked

Tags: javascript, php, checkbox, filter

I am having a hard time getting this to work.

I have some checkboxes with different colors. When the user clicks on one checkbox I want my indexMain DIV (which is the DIV where all items are shown) to show only the items with the selected color.

Also I want to avoid having a SUBMIT button, I want the DIV to load the selected items when the user clicks on one of the checkboxes.

So far I have this:

Javascript:

```
<script>
$(".regularCheckbox").change(function() {
var all_boxes = $('.regularCheckbox');
var checked_boxes = $('.regularCheckbox:checked');
var all_boxes_values = [];

checked_boxes.each(function(){
 var cb_value = $(this).val();
 all_boxes_values.push(cb_value);
});

var all_boxes_values_clean = all_boxes_values.join(", ");
console.log(all_boxes_values_clean);
$.get("index.php", {q: all_boxes_values_clean},
      function(result) {
       $("#indexMain").html(result);
      })
}); 
</script>
```

Form:

```
<form method="post" action="index.php">

<?php
$colors = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT color_base1 FROM item_descr ORDER BY color_base1");
while ($colorBoxes = mysql_fetch_array($colors))
{
echo "<input type='checkbox' id='checkbox-1-1' class='regularCheckbox' name='color' value='".$colorBoxes[color_base1]."' /><font class='similarItemsText'>   ".$colorBoxes[color_base1]."</font><br />";
}
?>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

PHP getting the results in my indexMain DIV:

```
$color = $_GET['color'];
```

Currently I need to press SUBMIT to have the data sent and the whole index.php page reloads...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with jQuery - use classes and hide any items that aren't part of that class.

```
<div id="items">
    <div name="item" class="blue">Something</div>
    <div name="item" class="red">Something else</div>
    <div name="item" class="green">Third thing</div>
</div>

<input type="checkbox" value="green" /> green
<input type="checkbox" value="red" /> red
<input type="checkbox" value="blue" /> blue

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $("input").on("click", function() { 
        if ($(this).attr("checked")) {
            $("#items div[name=item]:not(." + $(this).val()  + ")").hide();
            $("#items div[name=item]." + $(this).val()).show();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to go and check within a mysql database for items. Basically, when you click on the RED checkbox, I should run a SELECT.. WHERE color=$color (assuming I received value RED in $color)

Comment: If that's true, you're likely doing this wrong. Unless it's some sort of homework assignment.

Comment: Well, I'm building a clothing site where you should be able to filter by colors...

Comment: Each of those items can contain an attribute in its class *when they're output to the screen* that will allow you to do what I described above.

Comment: So I should assign the item's color to its class? That's too much changing I believe... in your code all divs are named "item" so all would be shown/hidden... :S

Comment: You don't need to copy/paste my code. It's just there as an example.

Comment: I'm not writing this to be condescending, but if you're building this site for income purposes, you might want to spend the money to have a professional with experience do the coding for you. You'll get a better, more maintainable product in the long run.

Comment: @Matt actually, if paging is used, one has to do the request for the items of a given color. If no paging is used, your solution is much better than the AJAXy one.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, this jquery snippet should help. Use jquery `val` function to get the values for the url in this example. When you click your form/button/etc it fires a function that loads a url into your named div.

```
$('#yourclickableobjectID').click( function(){
        $('#yourdivID').load("yoururl.php?yourquerystring=somestuff");
});
```